# Magento - Send Order PDF with an addition attribute to a defined email

Tags: email, pdf

I need to set an automatic email that notify the only one supplier that I've, that I receive an order, so they can start to produce it. I need so to send an attached pdf with an additional attribute, our internal code, that customer haven't to see in the pdf that him receive. For modify pdf, I'm trying myself, but I don't know how to make the automatic email with different pdf.. Can you help me pls? Thank you!